# Android flip animation between fragments with supported v4 jar file

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-fragmentactivity

Hi I am going to develop flip animation in android between the fragments transactions by using  supported jar file . Because of i want to implement the fragments for lower versions.I found the android [developers tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html) for flipping the animations  .But the supported library does not support the **Objactor animations**.after searching the internet i found i need to change the objacter animations to [Tween animations.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html) .how can i change those xml files to tween animations like bellow.

card_flip_left_in.xml

```
  <!-- Before rotating, immediately set the alpha to 0. -->
 <alpha
    android:valueFrom="1.0"
    android:valueTo="0.0"
    android:propertyName="alpha"
    android:duration="0" />

 <!-- Rotate. -->
 <rotate
    android:valueFrom="-180"
    android:valueTo="0"
    android:propertyName="rotationY"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_full"/>

<!-- Half-way through the rotation (see startOffset), set the alpha to 1. -->
<alpha
    android:valueFrom="0.0"
    android:valueTo="1.0"
    android:propertyName="alpha"
    android:startOffset="@integer/card_flip_time_half"
    android:duration="1" />
```

card_flip_left_out.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

   <!-- Rotate. -->
   <rotate
    android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_full"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:propertyName="rotationY"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="180" />

<!-- Half-way through the rotation (see startOffset), set the alpha to 0. -->
<alpha
    android:duration="1"
    android:propertyName="alpha"
    android:startOffset="@integer/card_flip_time_half"
    android:valueFrom="1.0"
    android:valueTo="0.0" />

 </set>
```

card_flip_right_in.xml

```
<!-- Before rotating, immediately set the alpha to 0. -->
<alpha
    android:duration="0"
    android:propertyName="alpha"
    android:valueFrom="1.0"
    android:valueTo="0.0" />

<!-- Rotate. -->
<rotate
    android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_full"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:propertyName="rotationY"
    android:valueFrom="180"
    android:valueTo="0" />

<!-- Half-way through the rotation (see startOffset), set the alpha to 1. -->
<alpha
    android:duration="1"
    android:propertyName="alpha"
    android:startOffset="@integer/card_flip_time_half"
    android:valueFrom="0.0"
    android:valueTo="1.0" />
  </set>
```

card_flip_right_out.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<!-- Rotate. -->
<rotate
    android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_full"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:propertyName="rotationY"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="-180" />

<!-- Half-way through the rotation (see startOffset), set the alpha to 0. -->
<alpha
    android:duration="1"
    android:propertyName="alpha"
    android:startOffset="@integer/card_flip_time_half"
    android:valueFrom="1.0"
    android:valueTo="0.0" />

 </set>
```

I changed those xml files but it does not works for us ..can any one please explain me what was the wrong i am doing.Please help me with sharing of use full tutorials and other sources..can any one provide me correct tween animations for those .

Answer (score 0):

If by "Objacter Animation" you mean ObjectAnimator, then it is not supported by compatibility lib. Instead you should take a look at NineOldAndroid library which brings Honeycomb+ animation API to older platforms: http://nineoldandroids.com/